# Failure to attach an existing EBS volume to a spot instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have been using AWS spot instances with persistance storage; something along [these lines.](https://medium.com/slavv/learning-machine-learning-on-the-cheap-persistent-aws-spot-instances-668e7294b6d8) I have been this successfuly for months with different instance types, and extended my volume several times as i got more data (128gb > 256gb > 512gb).

In my last experiment, I extended my ebs volume to 1TB, ran some batch process on a m4.16xlarge machine, and after one day, the second status check failed (instance reachability check); unfortunetly i don't have the system log for that moment now.

I thought it's a generic failure, and launched a new c4.8xlarge spot instance with the same ebs volume; no errors, ssh successful, data there.

Now i'm trying to create a new m4.16xlarge with the same ebs, but it fails; full server log [here](https://gist.github.com/olix20/4ce3ac51c7feb25bde6aa3e65862568e). I'm not able to mount the volume with this or any other instance type now.

Do you have ideas what might have wrong and how i can remedy this?

Comment: I suggest you read the log yourself and put the parts that look relevant into your question. No-one wants to read a massive log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem on your EBS volume is corrupted. Don't ask me how it became that way.

In the log, you'll see the following:

```
[   14.022730] EXT4-fs (xvdf1): ext4_check_descriptors: Checksum for group 0 failed (8312!=23362)
[   14.029039] EXT4-fs (xvdf1): group descriptors corrupted!
mount: mount /dev/xvdf1 on /permaroot failed: Structure needs cleaning
```

You'll need to fix your filesystem before trying to mount it again.

After some Googling, I found this, which you can try. But note that I do not warrant it's validity.

http://www.webdesignblog.asia/operating-systems/linux-os/ext4-fs-group-descriptors-corrupted-cannot-mount-disk-using-ubuntu/#sthash.XYgsfq3E.fTLnfoTc.dpbs

Comment: Thanks Matt, I managed to fix it by:
-creating a new instance and attaching the corrupted volume 
-running  `sudo fsck /dev/sdf1` (sdf being the device name for the volume) 

luckily all my working data is there, and all look good!